# openGL object not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, 32bit-64bit

I am working on a project, using both opencv and openGL, compiling with Cmake on OSX. I get this error message:

```
_glTexImage2D", referenced from:
  matToTexture(cv::Mat) in getimages.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I guess I have to use openGL 64bit instead of 32bit, but I don't know how to specify this.

Comment: please add the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

When compiling for MacOS X you must add the OpenGL framework. The compiler command line option is

```
-Framework OpenGL
```